# UEFI/GPT Windows 7 load failure in dual boot and no grub2

Tags: boot, grub2, bios, uefi, ahci

Configuration:

- Motherboard: ASRock X79 Extreme6
- Windows 7 installed on an Intel 40GB SSD (GPT partitioned)
- Ubuntu 14.04 on a Corsair 30GB SSD (ext4 and swap)

I had Windows 7 installed previously in UEFI mode, using 3 partitions (GPT), and it works fine if left alone. In UEFI BIOS settings I can see sometimes a Windows Boot Manager and other times (?) a "UEFI Intel" entry for INTEL HDD  and Windows will boot properly selecting the one available at that time.

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 after Windows 7 without changing any UEFI/BIOS settings. It works fine only if the BIOS is set with the Ubuntu partition as the first drive to boot in AHCI mode.

If both SSD drives are connected, the Windows 7 Intel boot drive can be chosen as first boot device but only as an "AHCI Intel drive" (neither Windows Boot Manager nor UEFI Intel device options are available in the BIOS boot menu) and Windows 7 will not load properly as long as the Ubuntu Crucial SSD is not physically disconnected. Windows will try, start booting for few seconds but will fail replacing the Windows 7 logo and that startup animation with with the old white progress bar and then and will notify that there is a issue and prompt the user to try to Load Windows 7 in Normal Mode again or try Recovery Mode in order to fix it.

If I let Windows Intel HDD boot via BIOS/UEFI - Windows Boot Manager selection, I may see the purple screen of grub2 is loaded for a while, but there's no selection for Ubuntu or Windows and/or then machine is not booting, showing a black screen and a small command prompt cursor blinking on top.

So far the only option I see to have Ubuntu boot side-by-side with Windows 7 is to reformat the Windows 7 SSD and set it boot in legacy mode with an MBR instead of GPT.

Per my understanding this is a quite complex issue to fix (Rod Smith's answer was pretty helpful: [UEFI boot on my Asus k52f](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175883/uefi-boot-on-my-asus-k52f)) but any other suggestions are welcome.

I find a bit odd that I can boot properly Windows7 SSD or an Ubuntu DVD using a DVD drive set in UEFI/BIOS in "AHCI mode" and w/ using "UEFI/Windows Boot Manager" booting option, but I cannot boot a secondary SSD/HDD with Ubuntu having the same UEFI/BIOS boot configuration. It looks like plugging in the second SSD [the Ubuntu partition] is interfering with the boot options in UEFI/BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

I reverted the Windows SSD to MBR and everything went back to normal. 
I don't miss the UEFI with GPT partitioning anyway, since while using MBR the boot time is faster for Windows 7 while using MBR (20 seconds). Ubuntu boots in 15 seconds and there's no longer any conflict between the Windows 7 and Ubuntu drives.